# Unwind from custom modal transition

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uiviewanimationtransition

I use custom transitions for modal segue, implemented using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning delegate. All segues setup via Storyboard.

I have two nav controllers, both have single root VC setup. Let's call them `1st NVC`, `1st VC`, `2nd NVC` and `2nd VC`.

`1st VC` adopts the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol, implementation simply returns animator:

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return [ModalTransitionAnimator new];
}

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return [ModalTransitionAnimator new];
}
```

When any segue happens from `1st VC` -> `2nd NVC`, `1st VC` catches the event in `prepareForSegue:` and assigns `transitioningDelegate` along with modalPresentationStyle because you cannot do that from IB:

```
UINavigationController* destination = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
destination.transitioningDelegate = self;
destination.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
```

So everything seems fine, I get a very cool animation running, destination controller shows up, all `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` fire in the right order.

And so now on screen, I have `2nd NVC` with `2nd VC` inside.

I tap "Cancel" button in Navigation bar, unwind action triggers on `1st VC`, but no backward animation happening. I mean in fact `2nd VC` is still on screen.

So apparently nobody calls dismissViewControllerAnimated. I suppose Storyboard is confused and can't find the way back because `2nd NVC` was initially modally presented and then some other controller requests unwinding. How do you deal with that normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the unwind chain and found that UIKit was not able to find the right unwind segue after state restoration. Before state restoration everything worked perfectly fine.

I fixed it manually and traversed my controllers hierarchy to return a controller that has unwind action defined:

```
- (UIViewController*)viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:(SEL)action fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController withSender:(id)sender {
    if([NSStringFromSelector(action) hasPrefix:@"unwindToInitialViewController"]) {
        return [[((UINavigationController*)self.centerViewController) viewControllers] firstObject];
    }

    UIViewController* c = [super viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:action fromViewController:fromViewController withSender:sender];
    DDLogInfo(@"%s = %@, c = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSStringFromSelector(action), c);

    return c;
}
```